# Improve scrollTop function

Tags: javascript, html, menu, load, scrolltop

the code below works fine but I'd like to improve the function because it's lagging when div loads. I have a menu in the middle of the page and the content only appears when I click on the menu, scrolling the menu right to the top and loading the external content in #showContent div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 2000);
    return false;
    })
});



$(document).ready(function() {
window.onload = init;
function init(){
$("#quemsomos").click(function(){
    $("#show_content").load("quem_somos.php");
});
$("#websites").click(function(){
    $("#show_content").load("websites.php");
});
$("#clientes").click(function(){
    $("#show_content").load("clientes.php");
});
$("#fotos").click(function(){
    $("#show_content").load("fotos.php");
});
}

});
```

Thanks in advance.